# Tag <a> isn't working. It doesn't recognize as a link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm using the default layout of Visual Studio, that has these links
[image]

However none of these links are working, and I'm not sure why. I haven't changed the code related to these, so I don't understad why this is happening.
Here is the code of the view:

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  style="z-index: -1;" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">AppFogos_WebAPI</a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my HomeController:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Can someone understand why this is happening?

EDIT:

Here is my UseEndpoints in the Startup class:

```
 app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


        });
```

Comment: Do you have a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file?

Comment: Yes, I have that file

Comment: Did you modify it? It should have a directive to include the MVC tag-helpers.

Comment: No, I haven't touch it. It has the tag that you mentioned

Comment: What does the `a` tag look like in the browser's developer tools? Can you include your `UseEndpoints` code?

Comment: I've added the useEndpoints to the post

Comment: Isn't `asp-area`, etc. for Razor Pages? Looks like you're using MVC? You should show the markup that gets produced.

Comment: Can you check the page source and verify what is rendered in those tag helper places?